# UITextView Stretches Over UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I have a UITextView taking up most of the screen, with a UIToolbar right underneath it. When the user edits the UITextView and types in enough text, the text view will gradually stretch right over the UIToolbar.

NoteDetail is the name of the text view. I've tried grabbing the size of the tool bar, which is about 50, and subtracting it from the frame size like so:

```
CGRect frame = NoteDetail.frame;
frame.size.height = NoteDetail.contentSize.height - 50;
NoteDetail.frame = frame;
```

This didn't cause the toolbar to stay put either, the text view just goes right over it once the text view grows big enough. I've also tried using auto layout and adding constraints, which didn't work well. Does anyone know how to prevent the textview from stretching over the tool bar when it starts to stretch?

Here is the screenshots, this:

[image]

Turns to this:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot, I'm not fully getting what you mean.

Comment: @reecon Sure thing, just added it in!

Comment: Are you doing this programmatically or by using storyboards/nibs?